# How to fix VS Code autocompletion to access all layers of a Python.NET - .NET assembly interface?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, .net-assembly, ironpython, python.net

I am programming in Python 3 in VS Code, using Python.NET to interface with a .NET based API (AudioPrecision.API.dll). I want to use autocomplete similar to Intellisense in Visual Studio, to make it easier to find and write APIs.

I have gotten most of the way there using the answers here:
[how-to-enable-intellisense-of-my-own-net-library-for-a-python-application-in-vi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064311/how-to-enable-intellisense-of-my-own-net-library-for-a-python-application-in-vi)

IE:

1. Install IronPython 2.7
2. Download IronPython-Stubs
3. Open cmd.exe, CD to the Stubs download directory.
4. Run IronPython-Stubs with the following args:

   ```
   "C:\\Program Files\\IronPython 2.7\\ipy.exe" -m ironstubs make AudioPrecision.API --path="c:\\Program Files\\Audio Precision\\APx500 8.0\\API\\AudioPrecision.API.dll" --output stubs.min --overwrite
   ```
5. Lastly,update ExtraPaths in VSCode Settings to include:

   ```
   C:\Users\...\\ironpython-stubs-master\ironpython-stubs-master\release\stubs.min
   ```

Unfortunately, while autocomplete now works at the first level, for example:

```
APx.AcousticResponse
```

[image: Auto-complete working in VSCode]

It does not work another level down, e.g.:

```
APx.AcousticResponse.RmsLevel
```

[image: Auto-complete not working in VSCode]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I posted that part as text because I needed to show the auto-complete window.

Comment: Whoops I meant "I posted that part as an image...."

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can try to set [python.autoComplete.extraPaths](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_autocomplete-settings) in your `settings.json` to pre-loaded IntelliSense.

Another way is to try to let IntelliSense to do a deeper level of retrieval.

You can add the following codes to your settings to do it as long as you are okay to pay perf cost.

```
  "python.analysis.packageIndexDepths": [
    {
      "depth": 100,
      "includeAllSymbols": true,
      "name": ""
    },
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain what you mean by "set python.autoComplete.extraPaths in your settings.json to pre-loaded IntelliSense"? I know what extraPaths is, but I don't know what you mean by "pre-loaded IntelliSense"?

Adding the example code to packageIndexDepths didn't seem to do anything.